# parse sublists of a list in python

Tags: python, list

In python, I need to parse a list consisting of sublists. If the first elements of some sublists are the same, I need to pick the sublist with the least 4th element; but if the 4th elements are also the same, then I need select the sublist with higher 3rd element. For example, in the following list, I need to select sublists 1, 4 and 5.

```
alignments=[["A","B","10","4"],["A","C","15","8"],["A","E","20","10"],\
            ["D","C","15","3"],\
            ["G","U","1","9"],["G","O","10","9"]]
```

I achieved it with the code below which is very cumbersome:

```
best_alignments=[]
best_al=alignments[0]
k=0
c=0

counter_list=[]
for al in alignments[1:]:
    c+=1
    if best_al[0]==al[0]:
        if best_al[3]==al[3]:
            if best_al[2]<al[2]:
                best_al=al
                counter_list.append(c-1)
            else:
                counter_list.append(c)
        else:
            counter_list.append(c)
    else:
        if k==0:
            best_al=al
            k+=1
        else:
            best_al=al
for index in sorted(counter_list, reverse=True):
    del alignments[index]   
for el in alignments:
    print(el)
```

I am sure there a much easier way to do that. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: The backslashes are not required inside brackets.

Comment: This might be more appropriate for Code Review Stack Exchange.

Comment: @AMC thanks, didn't know about that forum

Answer (score 1):

Here's a method that essentially does two passes over the data. First, it groups the data by the first item. Then, it returns the maximum as defined by your criteria, the *least* of the third element, and the most of the fourth (assuming you meant the integer value of the string).

```
from collections import defaultdict

def foo(alignments):
    grouped = defaultdict(list)
    for al in alignments:
        grouped[al[0]].append(al)
    return [
        max(v, key=lambda al: (-int(al[2]),int(al[3])))
        for v in grouped.values()
    ]
```

Pretty sure this is O(N) space and time, so not terribly inefficient.

In an Ipython repl:

```
In [3]: from collections import defaultdict
    ...: def foo(alignments):
    ...:     grouped = defaultdict(list)
    ...:     for al in alignments:
    ...:         grouped[al[0]].append(al)
    ...:     return [
    ...:         max(v, key=lambda al: (-int(al[2]),int(al[3])))
    ...:         for v in grouped.values()
    ...:     ]
    ...:

In [4]: foo([['A', 'B', '10', '4'],
    ...:  ['A', 'C', '15', '8'],
    ...:  ['A', 'E', '20', '10'],
    ...:  ['D', 'C', '15', '3'],
    ...:  ['G', 'U', '1', '9'],
    ...:  ['G', 'O', '10', '9']])
Out[4]: [['A', 'B', '10', '4'], ['D', 'C', '15', '3'], ['G', 'U', '1', '9']]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a sorted grouping where the sort order has multiple fields with different ascending/descending sequence.  So you can sort the list in accordance with the fields and sequence, then pick the first occurrence of items based on the sublist's first element:

```
a = [["A","B","10","4"],["A","C","15","8"],["A","E","20","10"],
     ["D","C","15","3"],
     ["G","U","1","9"],["G","O","10","9"]]

seen    = set()
sortKey = lambda sl: (sl[0],-int(sl[3]),sl[2])
first   = lambda sl: sl[0] not in seen and not seen.add(sl[0])   
result  = [ sl for sl in sorted(a,key=sortKey) if first(sl) ]
print(result)
# [['A', 'E', '20', '10'], ['D', 'C', '15', '3'], ['G', 'U', '1', '9']]
```

This uses the sorted function's key parameter to produce a sorting order that will combine the 3 fields (reversing the order for the second sort field).  Then filters the sorted list using a set to identify the first occurrence of the sublist's first field in each consecutive group.